# Insert javascript string into HTML with PHP in WP

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I need to create some widget for WP and in widget's setting will be `textarea`, where user can insert some JS code. And then my widget must inject this code to WP's `footer.php` with this function:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'inject_js', 10 );
```

In my `inject_js` I have:

```
function inject_js () { 

    echo esc_attr( get_option('js_code') );

}
```

Everything is working good and the code inserts into HTML, but I faced one problem. In my HTML I get something like this:

```
&lt;!-- BEGIN JS widget --&gt;
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    var __cp = {
        id: &quot;J4FGckYPdasda21OaTnqo6s7kMgeGXdTBAb6SgXMD-A&quot;
    };
```

As I understand I got the code from user's `textarea` in `string` type and I must do something with the quotes and other symbols, but I really don't know how to solve this issue, because I am new to PHP.

What PHP function must I use or it's possible to do with some WP functions?

I tried:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(esc_attr( get_option('js_code') ));
```

and

```
echo addslashes(esc_attr( get_option('js_code') ));
```

But nothing helped.

Comment: `echo  get_option('js_code');` ...`esc_attr` is escaping the value, funnily enough, so dont use that!

Comment: have you tried using html_decode? works fine ones I decode it my end.

Comment: @Steve, thanks a lot! It works for me! Maybe you post this comment as answer?

Comment: @user1779617 why encode the values (part of `esc_attr`) only to decode them again? Simply dont encode them in the 1st place

Comment: @TurakVladyslav Sure, give me a sec

Comment: aww sad times for me :(

Comment: @Steve, I'll accept it in 7 minutes. Thanks a lot for a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the effect of `esc_attr` - the function is html encoding (amoungst other things) the string.

It is designed for untrusted user input. As your code is specifically designed to accept javascript from a trusted source (the site owner), dont use it.

```
echo get_option('js_code');
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code in this :- like this:

```
 html_entity_decode(esc_attr( get_option('js_code')));
```